# Serving Website From S3 Using Cloud Front & Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I just recently moved my domain name from a hosting provider to Amazon. I want to host my website using S3 buckets and I originally I tried to set up my buckets to be `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` but I think my previous hosting provider took these bucket names because I cannot create them.

So I am looking at a work around now ... 
- created a new bucket with a unique name and put my website files in it 
- I set up Cloud Front to pull the files from that bucket 
- and lastly a Route 53 hosted zone with the CNAMES for `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` pointing to that Cloud Front.

Here is where my problem comes in. I cannot add `www.domain.com` to my CNAMEs in the Cloud Front. I get the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.CNAMEAlreadyExistsException: One or more of the CNAMEs you provided are already associated with a different resource. (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 409; Error Code: CNAMEAlreadyExists; Request ID: 19a9a141-8b15-11e6-aa8f-87e12f4b3abf)
```

However, it does accept `domain.com` ... so when I visit `domain.com` I get the proper website, but when I visit `www.domain.com` I get the old website.

I think it is due to the fact that I can't add that CNAME in my Cloud Front. How can I fix this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> You cannot add an alternate domain name to a CloudFront distribution if the alternate domain name already exists in another CloudFront distribution, even if your AWS account owns the other distribution.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-restrictions

This is the condition that would cause the error you're seeing.  If you already have another CloudFront distribution configured with this, then clearly that needs to be removed and then this would work.

Otherwise, the old provider may still have your domain configured on one of *their* CloudFront distributions -- so you need to persuade them to remove it, or you'll need to have AWS support assist you.  If the domain is already configured in CloudFront on another account, this can't be fixed by your actions alone.

AWS Support has a special process for handling exactly this situation: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/resolve-cnamealreadyexists-error/

Answer (score 0):

In case any of you guys have been playing with Zappa and/or AWS API Gateway before and CNAMEAlreadyExistsException occurred.

Just make sure with AWS CLI that domain you want to use isn't listed in AWS API Gateway anymore like this:

```
aws apigateway get-domain-names
```

In case you find it listed there:

```
aws apigateway delete-domain-name --domain-name <your-domain>
```

This fixed the issue for me. Piece!

BTW, I didn't find a way to list it or delete it through Web, just AWS API Gateway welcoming screens everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot I deployed an app using AWS Amplify in the past using the CNAMEs I wanted to use.

This is why I could not find the Cloudfront distribution on the `Cloudfront` console. Check to see if you have an AWS Amplify app using the desired names.